# Does a cell deprived of growth factors undergo apoptosis or G0 stasis?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling, growth, apoptosis

I can't seem to find a decisive answer on this topic in any of my textbooks. If a cell is deprived of growth factors does it:

- Activate apoptosis
- Go into the G0 phase but keep living?

Thanks.